# UE4 crash about attachment rules

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

The problem occurred when I try to change my default pawn's UPROPERTY value has name "MoveSpeed" in during collision function. Otherwise, there is no problem with that statement, it works really fine. When my default pawn collides with my "rock" pawn, am detecting collision and trying to reduce "MoveSpeed". Here is the code below:

```
void ARock_1::OnOverlapBegin(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComp, AActor* OtherActor, 
UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool FromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{
    Aduck* sa = Cast<Aduck>(OtherActor);
    sa->MoveSpeed = 99.f;
}
```

The `sa` is my pointer to other actor. So I can modify the pawn on pointer right? In editor when I try to play and test it, editor freezes like 10 sec after that crashes. So I checked the project crush log I saw these lines:

```
Ensure condition failed: AttachmentRules.LocationRule == EAttachmentRule::KeepRelative && AttachmentRules.RotationRule == EAttachmentRule::KeepRelative && AttachmentRules.ScaleRule == EAttachmentRule::KeepRelative [File:D:/Build/++UE4+Licensee/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/Components/SceneComponent.cpp] [Line: 1812]
AttachToComponent when called from a constructor is only setting up attachment and will always be treated as KeepRelative. Consider calling SetupAttachment directly instead.
```

In the constructer of "Aduck" class, I attached the components like so:

```
    if (!RootComponent)
    {
        RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("DuckBase"));
    }
    DuckDirection = CreateDefaultSubobject<UArrowComponent>(TEXT("DuckDirection"));
    DuckDirection->AttachToComponent(RootComponent, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepWorldTransform);

    DuckSprite = CreateDefaultSubobject<UPaperSpriteComponent>(TEXT("DuckSprite"));
    DuckSprite->AttachToComponent(DuckDirection, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepWorldTransform);

    USpringArmComponent* SpringArm = CreateDefaultSubobject< USpringArmComponent>(TEXT("SpringArm"));
    SpringArm->AttachToComponent(RootComponent, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepWorldTransform);

    CameraComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("Camera"));
    CameraComponent->AttachToComponent(SpringArm, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepWorldTransform);

    DikdortgenComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("Ordek"));
    DikdortgenComponent->AttachToComponent(RootComponent, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepWorldTransform);
```

My question is what difference between SetupAttachment and AttachToComponent. In which cases I should use them? Or am I doing wrong when I changing MoveSpeed? In documentation of `USceneComponent::SetupAttachment` it says:

> Initializes desired Attach Parent and SocketName to be attached to when the component is registered. Generally intended to be called from its Owning Actor's constructor and should be preferred over AttachToComponent when a component is not registered."

That's all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your two code snippets don't seem related. The calling AttackToComponent on components added in the constructor (as default object) with KeepWorldTransform as attachment rule is meaningless, because this (default) object doesn't exist in any world so cannot have a world transform. I think that's what your error is about. 
The error is also mentioning that SetupAttachment is preferable over AttachToComponent. However, if you want to have it use the existing world transform, you might want to call AttachToComponent elsewhere - for example in BeginPlay()

Comment: Be careful that Cast<Aduck>(OtherActor) can return nullptr if OtherActor isn't a Aduck, which will cause a runtime error when you try to access this pointer with ->

Answer (score -1):

Remove

```
if (!RootComponent)
{
    RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("DuckBase"));
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.